# In IE8, why am I getting a javascript error on my DocType line

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8, doctype

I am getting this error when running a webpage in internet explorer 8 (not sure if it matters but it happens when I load up a jquery ui dialog)

[image]

When I click yes, it brings up the IE8 javascript debugging tools but what is weird is that it shows the error being on the doctype line  . .

[image]

Can anyone explain what IE is trying to tell me and how I can debug this??

### Update:

in response to folks saying i need to remove the blank line at the top, here is my code.  There is no extra blank line on anything in my site.master file so i don't understand what it would take to remove this blank line that i see when i view source in IE8.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="DomainModel" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Mvc.Views.OrganisationalUnit" %> 
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage<Mvc.ViewModels.BaseViewModel>" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
```

Comment: The debugger is showing a "Line 1" with nothing in it, that's why people are questioning that. Does the Firefox debugger complain about it?

Comment: @Rob - no complaints from firefox at all.

Comment: Then it might be a debugger problem. Never, ever trust IE to do anything right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the whitespace at the top of the file (i.e. line 1).  If that doesn't help, try retyping the string manually to make sure no odd characters are hidden in there.  Otherwise, the code looks valid to me.

**Update:**
Try removing the line breaks between your import statements like this:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="DomainModel" %><%@ Import Namespace="Mvc.Views.OrganisationalUnit" %><%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage<Mvc.ViewModels.BaseViewModel>" %><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
```

Comment: see updated question (i added a response to you at the bottom) as i have NO blank line in my code (in the site.master file where the doctype line is listed).  any suggestions?

Comment: in terms of retyping, this is the line that comes out of the box with asp.net-mvc so i don't think its a typo

Comment: @ooo - can you try removing the line-breaks after your imports (i.e. concat them all together)? Seems like this wouldn't be a problem, but worth a shot. Example: see my edited answer